# pointer and reference question (linked lists)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, linked-list

I have the following code

```
struct Node {
  int accnumber;
  float balance;
  Node *next;
};

Node *A, *B;

int main() {
  A = NULL;  
  B = NULL;
  AddNode(A, 123, 99.87);
  AddNode(B, 789, 52.64);
  etc…
}

void AddNode(Node * & listpointer, int a, float b) {
// add a new node to the FRONT of the list
Node *temp;
  temp = new Node;
  temp->accnumber = a;
  temp->balance = b;
  temp->next = listpointer;
  listpointer = temp;
}
```

in this here `void AddNode(Node * & listpointer, int a, float b) {` what does `*& listpointer` mean exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node * &foo` is a [reference](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#overview-refs) to a `Node *`

So when you call it with

```
AddNode(A, 123, 99.87);
```

it will change A.

Comment: ok so from the top, A is a pointer to a structure, and in this function the argument is a pointer which is the deferenced address of a the pointer?

Comment: No, `listpointer` is just a reference to `A`. See the link in my answer. I.e., when you change `listpointer`, you're really changing `A`. It's an alias.

Comment: oh I see, so the '*' is actually acting as the pointer here. not the deference operator